# Database Indexing with Rails app

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, indexing

I have the tables: Products, Sub_Categories and Categories. Categories has many Sub_Categories, Sub_Categories belongs_to Categories and has many products and product belongs to sub_categories. My products table has a sub_category_id; my sub_category table has a category_id. What would be the most efficient way to index these tables to increase the app load time?

Comment: "What would be the most efficient way to index these tables to increase the app load time?"  I think you mean "decrease".

Comment: do you know what major queries getting fired against this? better to check query response time before and after applying the index w.r.t. major queries, making sure index you applied is worth. Otherwise no point just blindly maintaining indexes, see this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243475/how-do-you-identify-unused-indexes-in-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more info, for better access times for your queries, you would index these:

```
categories on id
subcategories on id
subcategories on category_id
product on id
product on sub_category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also use eager loading. For example, if you are going to need a category and several subcategories, load everything in fewer db queries with

```
Category.includes(:sub_categories).find(:id)
```

. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations.

Answer (score 0):

Anil's answer is correct, but as he intimates, your question is too vague.  I would suggest turning on query logging, and seeing which queries are taking up time in page loading.  Then take the offending queries, and type `EXPLAIN {query}` into a mysql prompt (which you can reach using `rails dbconsole` or the standalone mysql client provided by Oracle).  Look at the indices used in the bottleneck queries, and ask a more specific question.

I'm guessing that a lot of your queries are querying for products by their category ID.  Adding an indexed category_id column to Products might speed things up by avoiding a join, though then the onus on you to keep that column up-to-date.