# Locating unused indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

What method(s) does one use to locate unused indexes on an extant MYSQL installation? Percona has tools, but these boxes are Amazon RDS instances so we don't have access to the nuts and bolts side for use of those tools.

I did locate http://hackmysql.com/mysqlidxchk and I think it may be my only option at this point. I can manually comb through and look for indexes with duplicate leading keys, but that also seems counter productive.

Are there other solutions that I am not seeing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you identify unused indexes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243475/how-do-you-identify-unused-indexes-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: You are correct Jeremy. My prior searching was not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is [pt-index-usage](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-index-usage.html), but you don't necessarily need to run it against your RDS instance.

You could collect query logs,* and then run pt-index-usage against a snapshot of your database running anywhere, even on your laptop.  The tool just runs EXPLAIN for all queries in the log, and then reports any indexes that exist in the database but were not used by any EXPLAIN report.

RDS supports only table-based query logs, be careful of the overhead caused by this.

And you need to export the table-based query logs before using it as input to pt-index-usage.  Here' a script that can do the export:  https://github.com/billkarwin/bk-tools/blob/master/export-slow-log-table

MySQL 5.6 also has a new performance_schema table `table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-waits-summary-tables.html) and you can enable this to find out how frequently each index is loaded from disk into RAM, therefore it is being used.  Though you may not be using MySQL 5.6, and I don't know if you can enable performance_schema options on RDS anyway.

---

My colleague at Percona just posted a blog that confirms you can enable the performance_schema on Amazon RDS, though not through the Web UI.  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/08/21/amazon-rds-with-mysql-5-6-configuration-variables/

Comment: Good point Mr. Karwin. I think I will go down this route and see what I can generate. The link I posted to mysqlidxchk basically does the same thing. We are running on 5.1 so the performance_schema stuff is not available.

Answer (score 0):

[EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) along with your query is helpful, in this regard. Try it out, if it doesn't help, say so, with what you'd like to know that's missing as a comment and I'll look into it.

Comment: This is what I do now, but with our current setup there are hundreds of queries I would have to comb through. I have extensively used EXPLAIN to correct for slow query problems already, I am just moving on to the next phase of looking for vestigal indexes that are being unnecessarily updated.